# HereMap - Javascript - Switch to night Mode

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm beginner with HereMap- I'm using it With Js and php + html to display markers with status and bubbles.
What I want is to switch to night mode called `normal.night.grey` but I don't really know how to do this.

I've checked the offical support :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-service-maptype.html

And somes examples here :

http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#map-tiles__base-map-styles-and-modes

But that's not easy to understand ...

What i've done actually :

```
function addMarkerToGroup(group, coordinate, icon, html) {  
  var marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate,icon);
  marker.setData(html);
  group.addObject(marker);
}

function addInfoBubble(map) {
  var group = new H.map.Group();
  map.addObject(group);
  group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
      content: evt.target.getData()
    });
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
  }, false);  

  //
  // Here are some PHP code to generate markers from database
  //

}

// Map initialization code starts below:
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: 'myapikey'
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: new H.geo.Point(23.763987,11.753125),
  zoom: 2.95,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});

// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

// MapEvents enables the event system
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// create default UI with layers provided by the platform
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
addInfoBubble(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `defaultLayers.vector.normal.map` to `defaultLayers.normal.mapnight`

```
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.mapnight, {
  center: new H.geo.Point(23.763987,11.753125),
  zoom: 2.95,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/hwdr0vbp/1/)

Comment: If i put the code as it, i'm getting blank screen with ```TypeError: defaultLayers.normal is undefined``` as output. I've tried some syntaxes, but no success.   I've also tried ```baseLayers.normal.mapnight```, no success.

Answer (score 2):

Found it, thanks @user863.
Need to switch from raster to vector.

```
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.raster.normal.mapnight,{
  center: new H.geo.Point(23.563987,11.953125),
  zoom: 2.95,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
```

Comment: Yes, because from Here maps javascript API 3.1 the map has been divided into raster and vector